# How can I convert an ldap object to integer in a python function?

Tags: python, robotframework, python-ldap

I have created python function to search through an ldap object as below:

```
def my_search(l, baseDN, searchScope=ldap.SCOPE_ONELEVEL, searchFilter="objectClass=*", retrieveAttributes=None):
    logger.console("Reachedhere")
    try:
        logger.console("Reachedhereinsidetry\n")
        ldap_result_id =       l.search_s(baseDN,searchScope,searchFilter,retrieveAttributes)
        logger.console("Gotresult\n")
```

So I invoke this keyword now in a Robot Testcase as so:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation     This testsuite checks the LDAP functionalities of DB nodes.
Resource          ../../COMMON/Libraries/SDL-DB-COMMON-LIB.txt
Library           ../../COMMON/Libraries/pythonldap.py

*** Test Cases ***
Perform Ldap Operations
    ${ldapObj}    ldapopen    ${DB_1_EXT_APP_IP}
    Log to Console    ${ldapObj}
    ${SearchReturn}    my_search    ${ldapObj}    "uid=5000000,ds=CRIBER,o=D,dc=CN"    ldap.SCOPE_ONELEVEL    "objectClass=*"    None
```

When I run this TC, it throws me an error in the search like so:

```
TypeError: an integer is required
```

The error is definitely in "ldap_result_id =       l.search_s(baseDN,searchScope,searchFilter,retrieveAttributes)" line, since I'm able to print the earlier comments.

What is the issue here?

The issue here is the scope level which cannot be passed as above from Robot. The changes I did was :

```
def my_search(l, baseDN, searchScopeLevel, searchFilter="objectClass=*", retrieveAttributes=None):
try:
    if searchScopeLevel == 'ONE':
        searchScope=ldap.SCOPE_ONELEVEL
    elif searchScopeLevel == 'BASE':
        searchScope=ldap.SCOPE_BASE
    elif searchScopeLevel == 'SUB':
        searchScope=ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE
    ldap_result_id = l.search(baseDN,searchScope,searchFilter,retrieveAttributes)
```

Robot TC Changes :

```
*** Test Cases ***
Perform Ldap Operations
    ${ldapObj}    ldapopen    ${DB_1_EXT_APP_IP}
    ${SearchReturn}    my_search    ${ldapObj}        uid=205000000,ds=CRIBER,o=DEFT,dc=C    ONE    objectClass=*
```

And the issue is resolved. :)

Comment: Please give some details, at the very least where does it throw the error - guessing, in the my_search keyword. Will shoot an answer with the obvious problems because of the char limit here, but with this level of detail it's a wild guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming the exception is raised in the `my_search` method - by default the arguments to methods in RF are casted to string. Thus this call:

```
${SearchReturn}    my_search    ${ldapObj}    "uid=2620105000000,ds=SUBSCRIBER,o=DEFAULT,dc=C-NTDB"    ldap.SCOPE_ONELEVEL    "objectClass=*"    None
```

Has a number of issues:

- the `baseDN` argument will have an actual value `"uid=2620105000000,ds=SUBSCRIBER,o=DEFAULT,dc=C-NTDB"` - i.e. with the quotation marks included, thus probably not what you're aiming for; remove them
- the same for the `searchFilter` - remove the quotes in the call
- the `searchScope`, which probably is your problem, will receive the value ldap.SCOPE_ONELEVEL - a string with this content. This most probably is a constant defined in your ldap module; the safest bet that it'll work is to provide the integer value of that const - integers are given in the format `${1}`, but that's hardly sustainable. Perhaps you could export it and the other constants in the `COMMON/Libraries/pythonldap.py` library, and use it in the test cases
- finally, the `retrieveAttributes` argument will receive the string literal "None", not the `None` datatype you probably want; to get it, use this RF builtin variable - `${None}`

HTH, and again - provide more details to receive on-the-spot answers.

Comment: Thanks @Todor. The issue was in the ldap.SCOPE_ONELEVEL. I cannot pass that directly from Robot testcase. It throws this error. So what I did was I passed a ONE from Robot TC and then modified the python function to choose ldap.SCOPE_ONELEVEL. Updating in the original post.

Comment: That's a viable solution, great :)